# Fix error 0xc000000f with hiren's

Tags: boot

Today I had a problem with my computer, I was scanning my computer and suddenly it turned off, and when I turned it on a msg appeared that I need to fix the boot with cd windows installer.

As I don't have a DVD rom, I started looking for another way to fix it

I downloaded hirens, with my pendrive I"fixed" it using mbr utility.

Now I'm getting this error (0xc000000f).

I used mini XP to get into the OS and try to find a problem. My hard drive with windows data isn't visible in my computer, I went to disk management and it appears as "unallocated".

So which tool from hirens can I use in order to fix it?

Comment: Your 'fix' probably involved you wiping the partition table from your HDD or something equally dumb. Ordinarily I would recommend something like testdisk but I think it's better if you call in someone knowledgeable instead of worsening the situation by perhaps wiping your data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hirens has an entire Recovery Menu which includes Testdisk but I've had better luck with every tool but TestDisk (testDisk seemed to fix its creators 1988 IDE drives but not much in the real world).

Smart Partition Recovery repaired an obliterated partition table reporting as Unallocated after I ran it immediately upon unallocated detection,

After SPR restored it, It still required a through chkdsk also executed successfully from Hirens to recover a missing master file table that Windows could only report but refused to recover.

Comment: Thanks, well now a have another problem, i restated my computer and now when i use mini xp and go to disk management my disk appears but it says that i need to format it. Im not sure if this is worst than unallocated disk but i dont want to lose my data. What can i do? And that smart partition recovery, i cannot find it. I have 15.2 hirens version